# Find all of the elements of a subgroup generated by a $3$-cycle notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Question: Let $H$ be the subgroup of $A_n$ generated by $(123)$. Write down all elements of $H$.
 Here is my attempt:
 $H\le \langle 123 \rangle$ 
 $H$=$\langle a \rangle$ where the order of $a$=$n$ where $\langle a \rangle$=$\langle e,a,a^{2},....,a^{n-1} \rangle$
 since $\langle 123 \rangle$ has order $3$, $\langle 123 \rangle$=$\langle (e),(123),(23)(31) \rangle$
 I computed $(123)^{2}$ and $(123)^{3}$ since I had to order $3$ to come up with my answer for $\langle 123 \rangle$
 Did I do this right?

Comment: Yes, but it is more customary to write $(123)^2 = (132)$

Comment: ok will do. Is my $(123)^{3}$ correct?

Comment: Yes, $(123)^3=(1)$, but it is more customary to write $(123)^2=(132)$ instead of $(23)(31)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. $H = \langle (123) \rangle = \{e, (123), (132) \}$.